# Excel - fill cell with value 1 if another cell in same row is highlighted

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change the value in a cell in Col. A if the value in Col. B is highlighted yellow.

I've seen solutions to do the opposite (highlight row/cell based on value in Col. A like:  [Change background color of more than one cell on the same row when another cell has a certain numeric value in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855232/change-background-color-of-more-than-one-cell-on-the-same-row-when-another-cell) ), but I need to mark/flag the rows (with a number, like "1") with highlighting so that I can export this to a statistical program in a .csv or .txt format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to determine a cells fill colour is with VBA

Here's a UDF to do it

```
Function GetCellColour(r As Range) As Long
    GetCellColour = r.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
End Function
```

or if you prefer

```
Function GetCellColourIndex(r As Range) As Long
    GetCellColourIndex = r.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

then use it in a cell formula like

```
=IF(GetCellColour(A1)=65535,"Cell is yellow","")
```

or

```
=IF(GetCellColourindex(A2)=6,"Cell is yellow","")
```